# Change default status code in .NET core 6 middleware

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, .net-6.0

Let me explain the scenario for better understanding.

I've developed API in .NET core 6. There are few layers in API project.

All the data manipulation is happening in service layer and I am managing exception in service layer only. To standardized the response I am returning one object which contains three members.

1.Data - If response is ok then sending data else it will be null.

2.Status - response status code

3.Message - custom message

Now the issues is because I am handing everything in service layer, Controller will always return response with status code 200. Actual status is in the custom object.

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginVM loginVM)
{
    loginVM.Password = loginVM.Password.Encrypt();
    CurrentResponse response = _accountService.GetValidUser(loginVM);

    User user = (User)(response.Data);

    if (user != null)
    {
        response = GetDetails(response, user, loginVM.TimeZone);

        return Ok(response);
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```

**Service Layer Code**

```
public CurrentResponse GetValidUser(LoginVM loginVM)
{
    try
    {
        User user = _accountRepository.GetValidUser(loginVM.Email, loginVM.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid Credentials");
            
            return _currentResponse;
        }

        UserVSCompany userVSCompany = _userVSCompanyRepository.GetDefaultCompanyByUserId(user.Id);
        string companyId = "0";

        if(userVSCompany != null)
        {
            companyId = userVSCompany.CompanyId.ToString();
            user.CompanyId = userVSCompany.CompanyId;
        }

        user.ImageName = $"{Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.Instance.UploadDirectoryPath}/{UploadDirectories.UserProfileImage}/{companyId}/{user.ImageName}";
        Company company = _companyRepository.FindByCondition(p => p.Id == user.CompanyId);

        if(company != null)
        {
            if(!company.IsActive)
            {
                CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your organisation is not activated");

                return _currentResponse;
            }

            if(company.IsDeleted)
            {
                CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Organization has been deleted");

                return _currentResponse;
            }
        }
       
        if (!user.IsActive)
        {
            CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your account is not activated");
        }
        else if (user.IsDeleted)
        {
            CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your account has been deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            if (company != null)
            {
                user.CompanyName = company.Name;
            }

            var userRoleDetails = _userRoleRepository.FindByUserIdAndCompanyId(user.Id, user.CompanyId);

            user.RoleName = userRoleDetails.Name;
            user.RoleId = userRoleDetails.Id;

            CreateResponse(user, HttpStatusCode.OK, "User is valid");
        }

        return _currentResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        CreateResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exc.ToString());
        return _currentResponse;
    }
}
```

Now mobile developer has to write condition to check actual status because of my custom object.

**Solution**
I can change the code in controller where I need to check status of my custom object but this is not a proper way as I need to make changes in whole project.

**How can I create a response wrapper middleware where I can read the response object and set status code of response?**

Any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a [Result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#result-filters) and register it globally (also explained in the link).

Comment: I tried with filters and in the filter I added below line, but still It is returning same status code.


context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;

Comment: Instead of working around the problem you are facing now, I would recommend that you reconsider the design of your app.
The service layer should not be responsible for determining the http response code. That is the responsibility of the controller/web layer. 
The service layer should return a `Result` object which is either success of fail with the right error message. Check LanguageExt.

Comment: that is not the solution.

Comment: Maybe or maybe not you can adjust the response in the middleware, it depends on when and how you change things, but I don't see a definition of your middleware or your app setup (`app.Use...`) which would all be helpful to answer this question. ~ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: asp net mvc and razor pages are built around the http spec. You will always have problems going against the grain. Use the response codes, they are there for a reason.